# Hide All but first unique data attribute dynamically?

Tags: jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

How could I use jQuery to hide all but the first instance of a data attribute using CSS/Jquery?

Example:

```
 <ul>
  <li data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
  <li data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li> 
  <li data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>
  <li data-animal-type="spider">GreyWidow</li> 
 </ul>
```

So in this example, "greywidow" would not show. It needs to work dynamically as the data-type attributes and content are not known.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could loop through each `li` element and check whether that element is the `:first` one with the given `data-animal-type`:

```js
$('li').each(function() { 
  var $li = $(this);
  $li.toggle($li.is($('li[data-animal-type="' + $li.data('animal-type') + '"]:first')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
  <li data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>
  <li data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>
  <li data-animal-type="spider">GreyWidow</li>
</ul>
```